# Having trouble passing variables between pages through php

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, foreach, hidden-field

So here's the code on the first page:

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect(
  ':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'root',
  'root'
);
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db('onlineform', $db);
$newQuery1 = mysql_query("SELECT newCampSessions FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error ' . mysql_error());
$newFoo = mysql_fetch_array($newQuery1);
        $newQuery2 = mysql_query("SELECT pricePerWeek FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error ' . mysql_error());
$newFoo1 = mysql_fetch_array($newQuery2);
$newOldString = $newFoo['newCampSessions'];
$newOldString2 = $newFoo1['pricePerWeek'];
$newChangedString = unserialize($newOldString);
$newChangedString2 = unserialize($newOldString2);
sql_close();
?>
<html>
<head> (all the tags in here) </head>
<body>
<form id="paymentform" action="amd8.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="pricePerWeek" value="<?php echo $newChangedString2 ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="specificWeek" value="<?php echo $newChangedString ?>"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

There's more to the first page, but I just provided the codes that are relevant. Everything is working php-wise on the first page.

When I try and pass it onto the 2nd page, I'm getting a value of NULL for those specific arrays I'm trying to pass over.

**amd8.php:**

```
<?php

if ($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $newString = $_POST['pricePerWeek'];
    $newString2 = $_POST['specificWeek'];
}


$db = mysql_connect(
  ':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'root',
  'root'
);
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db('onlineform', $db);

    $newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT newPrice,numberOfWeeks FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$newRow = mysql_fetch_row($newQuery);
$limit = $newRow[1];

    $totalPrice = 0;

    if (isset($_SESSION['campsessions']))
    {   

            for ($count == 0; $count < $limit; $count=$count+1)
        {

                foreach ($_SESSION['campsessions'] as $campsessions)
                {
            if ($campsessions == ($newString[$count]))
            {
                $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $newString2[$count];
            }
                } 
        }   
    }

?>

<html>
<head>(header info)</head>
<body>
<p>
<?php echo gettype($newString2);
      echo gettype($newString);
 ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `gettypes()` **I'm trying to echo are the ones that are giving me a value of NULL**

Comment: you're not passing formSubmit in your form, so $_POST['formSubmit'] is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your submit button to `formSubmit` to make the if statement return true. Change your form like this and it should work:

```
<form id="paymentform" action="amd8.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="pricePerWeek" value="<?php echo $newChangedString2 ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="specificWeek" value="<?php echo $newChangedString ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="formSubmit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first if to:

```
if ($_POST['pricePerWeek'] || $_POST['specificWeek'])
```

In alternative, if you prefer, you can add a hidden input to the form, and leave the if as is.

```
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
```